# Audio Encoding software or script

Tags: audio, encoding, converters

Does a program exist that will allow me to batch covert files and do the following:

a) Search for MP3's on my drive
b) transcode from 128 kbs/sec to 64 kbs/sec
c) switch from Stereo to Mono
d) save and overwrite the previous file

Or is their anyway I could write a script to perform this task on a windows desktop?

Comment: FFMPG. It can do the conversion, but it does not have search functionality. The problem is that the location of a lot of the MP3's are unknown. They exist on a corporate drive. There are thousands of them that need to be converted. We were hoping to be able to do a wildcard search, and conversion in a batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on un*x, the tool of choice for batch-processing is `find`:

```
find /path/to/foo -name "*.mp3"
```

will give you all files matching "*.mp3" in /path/to/foo and all it's subdirectories.

since`find` is a beast, you probably want to check it's manpage.

you can pass a script to `find` that is called for each match. e.g. the following will do an "ls -l" on all *files* (excluding directories named e.g. "mysounds.mp3/"; that's what the `-type f` is for):

```
find /path/to/foo -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec ls -l \{\} \;
```

note, that the curly braces and the semicolon are escaped with backticks, in order to prevent the shell from interpreting those special characters.

if you have a script (named `convertmp3.sh` and which is sitting in your current working directory) that does an in-place conversion (overwriting the old file), you can do:

```
find /path/to/foo -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec ./convertmp3.sh \{\} \;
```

such a script could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
INFILE="$1"
TMPFILE="${INFILE}.mp3"
ffmpeg -i "${INFILE}" -ac 1 -b 64k "${TMPFILE}" && mv "${TMPFILE}" "${INFILE}"
```

note that i'm using a temporary file here, because else `ffmpeg` would start overwriting the source file before it has fully read it, and thus stopping with an error.
also do not forget the quotes around the filenames, to protect against filenames with spaces and the like.

also note, that this script does not check whether the input file is already in the desired format, thus potentially re-encoding it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  With some modifications that we'll add to it, this is what we were looking for.